# How to filter a list and collect it's index to a string result use RxJava2?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

This is my code to collect checkbox index that checked and get a string result.

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxList.size(); i++) {
        if (checkBoxList.get(i).isChecked()) {
            sb.append((i + 1) % 7 + 1);
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
```

But i want to implement it use RxJava2 like this.

> Observable.fromArray(checkBoxList).filter(..).subscribe(..)....

Who has ideas?
Thanks for first!

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: @akarnokd Use Rxjava2 traverse checkBoxList and filter the CheckBox checked then collect it's index and get string result like the above loop done .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest reading a book or introductory blog post about RxJava where you will find the basic building blocks for this type of flow:

```
  Observable.range(0, checkBoxList.size())
  .filter(idx -> checkBoxList.get(idx).isChecked())
  .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, idx) -> 
       sb.append((idx + 1) % 7 + 1).append(",")
  );
```